# Virtualbox not detecting USB devices on both Linux and Windows Guest OSs

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I am running Virtualbox Version 6.0.4 r128413 on Windows 10 host 64bit. The problem is that plugged-in USB devices are available in USB filters yet none of them are being available in any guest OS(both windows and linux guests). Latest Virtualbox guest additions and extension pack are already installed. I have tried troubleshooting with the instructions available in [USB basics and troubleshooting](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=82639), but nothing seems to work.

Outputs of following commands in this link [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=91943).

```
VBoxManage list usbhost

VBoxManage list usbfilters

VBoxManage showvminfo "vm-name"
```

and the guest VM's log is uploaded as `Kali-Linux-XFCE-2019-02-20-22-36-12.log`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was happening because I had installed Wireshark along with USBPcap. After removing USBPcap and manually installing USB drivers for virtualbox everything is working perfectly.

**EDIT**: (For anyone facing problem with USB driver installation)

Virtualbox USB driver can be manually installed as follows-

1. Right click on `<install-path>\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\USB\device\VBoxUSB.inf` and press install.
2. This will install `VBoxUSB.sys`(USB driver file) in `system32/drivers` folder .
3. Check `system32/drivers` folder for `VBoxUSB.sys`.

Comment: This issue has been driving me mad for months. Thanks.  More info here: https://github.com/desowin/usbpcap/issues/62